# uploading an app to AppStore

Tags: xcode, xcode4, app-store

It's made me crazy! it's so hard upload an app to appStore!!

I'm working now with Application Loader.

I solved a lot of mistakes, and there is one more I can't, this one:

> Application failed codesign verification. The signature was invalid, contains disallowed entitlements, or it was not signed with an Iphone Distribution Certificate.

I read I have to set:

> Product-> Edit scene -> archive -> release.

what I'm missing?

### Edit

Is that what I should have?

[image]

I think is this, but I'm having so many trouble that I'm not sure about anything!

I have this distribution certificate, next step is install, but, where should I do this? Xcode? application uploader? in the same website?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using a distribution certificate?

Comment: I dont know! how can I know that?

Comment: Have you ever made a distribution certificate on http://developer.apple.com?

Comment: That is a development certificate. You need a distribution cert too

Answer (score 2):

Try creating a Distribution Certificate:

1. Go to http://developer.apple.com
2. Click Member Center
3. Sign in with your apple ID
4. Click iOS provisioning Portal
5. Click Certificates
6. Click Distribution    (From this point I'm working from memory as I have already done this)
7. Follow the instructions for making a certificate (this will involve Keychain Access)
8. Download your certificate and open it.
9. Go back to the provisioning portal and click provisioning
10. Click distribution
11. Make and download a distribution profile.
12. Install that profile.
13. Make sure you are building with this when you create the archive

Comment: I edited my first post, I'm at the 12 point, and I dont know how to continue. Thanks

Comment: I'm just desperate. I have this error in my xcode Check dependencies

Code Sign error: No unexpired provisioning profiles found that contain any of the keychain's signing certificates

Comment: I thought it was done before, and when I added the new one, I deleted a profile I made yesterday (I'm more then one day with this!! unbelieble!)

Comment: Don't worry, just take your time. The first time I released an app it took two of us about 2 days. It's not the most simple process until you get the hang of it